# find enclosed plus NP

Tags: grammar

> Dear Mr. Potter,
>
> We are pleased to inform you that you have been accepted at Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. **Please find enclosed a list of all necessary books and equipment**.
>
> Term begins on September 1. We await your owl by no later than July 31.
>
> Yours sincerely,
>
> Minerva McGonagall, 
>    Deputy Headmistress
>
> *-- Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone by J.K. Rowling*

Is the clause like the below on [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/enclosed): “Please find enclosed a cheque for £100”, or is it interpreted otherwise: like enclosed is object predicative -- object [list of all necessary books and equipment.] + object predicative [enclosed]?

Comment: You nailed it, but there's no *or*--that's how you interpret the OALD sentence, too. "We enclose a list/a cheque, and we trust you are pleased to find it."

Comment: Not quite; 'please' is here a gentle imperative to look for the enclosure rather than an expected emotion at finding it. Paraphrased: "We've enclosed (with this letter) a list - please look for it; we trust that you will find it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like the OALD example that you have provided.  It's a formal term generally used in mail to mention something that is sent along with the letter.